# Error building viewcontroller.war with Maven

Tags: maven, war, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am tyring to build ear application in oracle JDeveloper using maven. I get this error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ViewController: Could not resolve dependencies for project sx:ViewController:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: sx:Model:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT, com.oracle.adf.library:ApachePOI:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Wls-API-Security:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Templates:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Docx4j:pom:12.1.2-0-0: Could not find artifact sx:Model:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
>       org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project ViewController: Could not resolve dependencies for project sx:ViewController:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: sx:Model:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT, com.oracle.adf.library:ApachePOI:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Wls-API-Security:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Templates:pom:12.1.2-0-0, com.oracle.adf.library:Docx4j:pom:12.1.2-0-0: Could not find artifact sx:Model:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

I have manualy installed missing jars to my local maven repository, also i have added them to dependencies, am I missing some settings for dependencies? Also i have built model.war, but it is also not found.

Does maven in JDeveloper automatically put created war into repository?
how can i tell JDeveloper or maven that required dependencies are in the repository?

viewcontroller.pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sx</groupId>
  <artifactId>ViewController</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Generated POM from JDeveloper for project ViewController</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sx</groupId>
      <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSP-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSF</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSTL</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Page-Flow-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Controller-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Controller-Schema</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Faces-Runtime-11</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Common-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Web-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>MDS-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>MDS-Runtime-Dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Commons-Beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Commons-Logging</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Commons-Collections</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-DVT-Faces-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-DVT-Faces-Databinding-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-DVT-Faces-Databinding-MDS-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oracle-JEWT</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Faces-Databinding-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Common-Web-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Faces-Change-Manager-Runtime-11</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ApachePOI</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Wls-API-Security</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Resource-Bundle-Support</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Resource-Bundle-Variable-Resolver</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Templates</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
      <artifactId>sxreports</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Docx4j</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>/C:/Users/btsgrenov/.m2/repository/com/oracle/adf/library/Docx4j/12.1.2-0-0/Docx4j-12.1.2-0-0.pom.lastUpdated</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Servlet-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oracle-XML-Parser-v2</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JDeveloper-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Model-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BC4J-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oracle-JDBC</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Connection-Manager</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BC4J-Oracle-Domains</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bea.core.weblogic.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bea.core.weblogic.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>identity</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>
                  ../../LIBS/
                </source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>
            public_html/
          </webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojmake</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojmake>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojmake.exe
          </ojmake>
          <files>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\ViewController\ViewController.jpr
          </files>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdeploy</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojdeploy>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojdeploy.exe
          </ojdeploy>
          <workspace>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\SXDOCS.jws
          </workspace>
          <project>
            ViewController
          </project>
          <profile>
            abc
          </profile>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <outputDirectory>classes/</outputDirectory>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies/>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

model.pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sx</groupId>
  <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Generated POM from JDeveloper for project Model</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BC4J-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Model-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>MDS-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>MDS-Runtime-Dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BC4J-Security</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oracle-JDBC</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BC4J-Oracle-Domains</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Resource-Bundle-Support</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Common-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ADF-Faces-Runtime-11</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSF</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSP-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JSTL</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Resource-Bundle-Variable-Resolver</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
      <artifactId>sxreports</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <outputDirectory>classes/</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>
            public_html/
          </webappDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojmake</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojmake>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojmake.exe
          </ojmake>
          <files>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\Model\Model.jpr
          </files>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdeploy</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojdeploy>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojdeploy.exe
          </ojdeploy>
          <workspace>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\SXDOCS.jws
          </workspace>
          <project>
            Model
          </project>
          <profile>
            SXWEB_Project1_adflib
          </profile>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

application.pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sx</groupId>
  <artifactId>SXDOCS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Super POM for SXDOCS</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojmake</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojmake>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojmake.exe
          </ojmake>
          <files>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\SXDOCS.jws
          </files>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdeploy</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojdeploy>
            C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojdeploy.exe
          </ojdeploy>
          <workspace>
            C:\JDeveloper\mywork\sxdocsLAST\SXDOCS\SXDOCS.jws
          </workspace>
          <profile>
            application_production
          </profile>
          <usemaven>
            true
          </usemaven>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>Model</module>
    <module>ViewController</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sx</groupId>
      <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sx</groupId>
      <artifactId>ViewController</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

log
[log file from build](https://yadi.sk/i/RtgdqxDBe7b4P)

Comment: "Does maven in JDeveloper automatically put created war into repository?" No, it doesn't, you need to run `mvn install <something>` (or use the corresponding UI command) to move `<something>` to your local repo. Please post your `POM` file.

Comment: @watery I've added code from pom files, these lines might give some clue: [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.adf.library:ApachePOI:pom:12.1.2-0-0 is missing, no dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.adf.library:Wls-API-Security:pom:12.1.2-0-0 is missing, no dependency information available  [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.adf.library:Templates:pom:12.1.2-0-0 is missing, no dependency information available. **If i am using default profile to deploy(ant) it works fine, all libs used before are added to repo**

Comment: @watery added log from build with debug info

Comment: If you manually copied the jars (i.e. by copy-pasting them) in your repo, then that won't work as each artifact must lay close to its `POM`. Beside that, I can't find anything about `com.oracle.adf.plugin` neither [here](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.oracle.adf.plugin) or [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~com.oracle.adf.plugin), so maybe those are located in some third party repo whose address you need to find and declare in your `POM`.